# Digispark clone not recognised when plugged in

Tags: power

When I plug in my digispark clone the computer doesn't make any sounds or some kind of acknowledgement that it has been plugged in. Anyone know why this may be or is it just a dodgy clone?

Comment: possibly not pre programmed

Answer (score 3):

The Digispark does not use a "standard" USB-to-Serial chip but is dependent on a special bootloader called "micronucleus" that makes it (sort of) act like a USB device.

Below is a description of the steps you need to perform for a Windows system and the Arduino IDE.

1. First, you will need to install a Windows driver for Micronucleus: [Zadig USB driver](https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus/tree/master/windows_driver_installer)

If your ATTiny is recognized by Windows after performing the driver installation, then all is fine and you can skip to step 4.

If Windows still does not recognize your Digispark clone, its ATTiny processor might not have come with micronucleus pre-programmed and you need to perform steps 2 and 3. Unfortunately this is for advanced users and might be difficult if you're inexperienced with electronics and/or Arduino.

2. [Download Micronucleus from Github](https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus)
3. Follow [This tutorial from Digispark](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-an-attiny-bootloader-with-virtual-usb/install-micronucleus) to install micronucleus on your ATTiny. You will need another Arduino (Uno, Nano, Mega, Mega2560, ... or clone) for that.
4. Then follow [This tutorial from Digistump](https://digistump.com/wiki/digispark/tutorials/connecting) to enable the Arduino IDE to program your Digispark clone directly from USB.

Comment: I assume one wants t85_default.hex for an ATTiny85 IC?

Comment: @Scott Correct, you need to download it from the Github repository (linked to by the Digispark site), or from the zip file in the 3rd step (it's under *firmware/releases*).

Comment: yeah I got that part and found the repository but there were about 9 or 10 hex images in there with no documention I could see as to what was what

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a driver problem.

If you are on Windows, check your Device Manager and see if the new device is detected and has proper driver installed. If it is, you should see a COM port added when you attach the board.

There are different USB chips that manufacturers use (CH340G and FT232RL, as far as I know), and not all of them have their drivers already installed on Windows.

Check your board to see what chip it is, google for the drivers and the setup procedure for your OS.

You can also check [Digispark Installation Instructions](https://digistump.com/wiki/digispark/tutorials/connecting) and try the driver they provide.